# How to change a let number in react using a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the value of let `showtext` to change the text that is displayed.
When I change the value of `showtext` in code the text changes, but the variable doesn't change when I click the button.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line eslint-comments/disable-enable-pair
/* eslint-disable no-eval */

import * as React from "react";
import "../../../styles/colour_sdgs.css";
import "../../../styles/infotext.css";
import Logo from "../../../SDGLogos/Goal-06.png";

let showtext = 1;
const sdg = "sdg06";
const text = {
    1: `text1`,
    2: `text2`,
};

function incrementCount(): void {
    showtext++;
}

function decrementCount(): void {
    showtext--;
}

export const sdg06infotext = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={`colour_${sdg}`}>
                <div className="header">
                    Hochwertige Bildung <img className="sdglogo" alt="logo" src={Logo} />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="infotextbox">
                <p> {text[showtext]} </p>

                <p>blabla</p>
                <p>
                  other text
                </p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" onClick={incrementCount}>
                {showtext}+
            </button>
            <button type="button" onClick={decrementCount}>
                {showtext}-
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: `showtext` [must be state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for it to have an effect on a new render.

Comment: but how can i use states with functions?  do i need to make a class out of it with constructor etc?

Comment: `showtext` does change on the button click; what doesn't change is React element tree and therefore the DOM stays the same - in other words the state of your app is out of sync with the view. You need to tell React to rerender on `showtext` change.

Comment: @marzelin so how do i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showtext` does change on the button click; what doesn't change is React element tree and therefore the DOM stays the same - in other words the state of your app is out of sync with the view. You need to tell React to rerender on `showtext` change.

To make it work you need to move `showtext` and the functions that use it inside of the component and make it a state value:

```js
const sdg = "sdg06";
const text = {
    1: `text1`,
    2: `text2`,
};

const Sdg06infotext = () => {
    let [showtext, setText] = React.useState(1);

    function incrementCount(): void {
        setText(++showtext);
    }

    function decrementCount(): void {
        setText(--showtext);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={`colour_${sdg}`}>
                <div className="header">
                    Hochwertige Bildung
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="infotextbox">
                <p> {text[showtext]} </p>

                <p>blabla</p>
                <p>
                  other text
                </p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" onClick={incrementCount}>
                {showtext}+
            </button>
            <button type="button" onClick={decrementCount}>
                {showtext}-
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Sdg06infotext/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So i tried your version, but i get 2 errors. The first one is EsLint that wants to use const not let. Second one is here: renderer.render(<sdg06infotext/>, document.getElementById("root")) and the error is Property 'sdg06infotext' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Comment: you can change `let` to `const` and the reason for the second error is that component names need to be capitalized (start with an uppercase letter), otherwise they are treated as html elements and `sdg06infotext` is not a valid html element.

Comment: when i change it to const i can not reassign it with incrementCount and get an error.

Comment: When i change sdg06infotext to Sdg06infotext i get 2 errors too: 'Sdg06infotext' is not defined. And Cannot find name 'Sdg06infotext'. Did you mean 'sdg06infotext'?

Comment: the name of the component needs to match what you use in the jsx - when you change one be sure to change the other. Actually the value of `showtext` is changed somewhere in the code so eslint shouldn't error on using `let`; that's weird. Anyway, you can change `++showtext` to `showtext + 1` and the `--showtext` to `showtext - 1`.

Comment: i told eslint to shut up and it should be fine but i still struggle with the render part

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a version of React (16.8.0 or above) that [supports hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) you can use `useState` to maintain the count.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

  function increment() {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }

  function decrement() {
    setCount(count - 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>text{count}</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: what is the second part <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>. You both have it and im not sure what it is

Comment: [It's how we get React snippets work on the site.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) If you're already using React you don't need to worry about that bit.

Comment: Thank you :D. So its used for this run code snippset button right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you have React up and running these examples should simply guide you in the right direction.